# Should I use KVM or Xen ? What are the main differences?

Tags: kvm, graphics, xen, gpu

I've spent a few hours trying to understand the differences between KVM and Xen without much succes. So both are Type 1 Hypervisors with comparable performances ([source](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-1510-virt)) and I don't understand what differenciates them.

The only specific needs I have are that the guest OS isn't able to interract with the hosts's files (which seems to be the default behaviour) and that both the host and the guest can use their own GPU for video rendering. That seems not to be a problem as both Xen and KVM support some kind of "GPU/VGA/PCI pass-through" as long as there are two physical graphics cards.

So what are the differences between Xen and KVM ? Is one or the other more suitable for graphical performances ?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

KVM is normally supported already via libvirt and the kernels in modern distros without much hassle. You just need a CPU that has VT-d extensions (or AMD-V for AMD processors), and your BIOS has to have it enabled. After that, it's all about installing the necessary packages to get it going.

XEN, yes, does support it. Xen is literally its own platform. A long time back, it was once known that Xen had the most documentation on IOMMU and VGA passthrough. Now, you'll find multitudes of users using KVM in a similar manner with high rates of success (I am one of them, using F23, GTX970 to a Windows VM for gaming).

To answer your question though, the primary difference is that KVM is has had a **lot** of work put into it by Red Hat and the open source community, since Red Hat dropped Xen in 2009 in favor of KVM. This should in no way sway your options. You'll find varying benchmarks that show KVM outperforming Xen on numerous occasions, with KVM just being 5% slower than bare metal. Now, Xen does come with a bigger feature set than KVM out of the box, but a lot of it is for migrations and other things that you would consider "enterprise".

I personally believe you should try both and see what works better for you. There are many guides to choose from and to work on, based on your distribution of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it seems that for the end user the main difference is who makes the software, I couldn't find much more about functionnal differences despite searching for 5 or 6 hours. Also I've found a [powerpoint report from the CERN](https://indico.cern.ch/event/45282/session/7/contribution/5/attachments/945535/1341281/XEN_KVM.ppt). It seems to be more reliable than other tests as it was done with a high number of VMs which is closer to a typical use of that kind of setup.